# A process is running and I cannot find what is it and cannot kill that!

Tags: bash, ubuntu, process, cpu

I've found a bash process in my Ubuntu server that is consuming all of my CPU
I've try to kill this process by `kill -9` and after kill the process run automatically
How can find what is this process and where is the source of this process and how to kill that for always!
[image]

here is a screen shot of `htop`
these first processes is my problem

Comment: If the process is restart automatically, the culprit may be the father. Let’s n the CPU greedy process. Type `ps xao ppid,pid | grep n` where you replace n by the right value. This displays the parent process ID with the process ID, then you can identify the parent. `ps -p ppid` can show the ppid process (ppid replaced by the parent ID, you can decide to kill this one.

Comment: the parent process id is `1` ! and this process cannot be killed!

Comment: Yes, killing ***1,init*** if you can won’t be a good to do. I have no other ideas.

Comment: @miladnekooei but: process 1 doesn't usually spawn bash directly. (Frederic is right in principle, 1 is "the init-equivalent process", it's just `systemd` under ubuntu, not `init`.) You'll need to figure out, with the help of `journalctl`, and `systemctl status` what it's currently doing. Again, Systemd doesn't usually spawn bash directly – but there might be some service that is actually a bash script.

Comment: You may have been hacked: the CPU greedy processes might in fact be bitcoin miners or something similar, pretending to be shells in order to avoid being noticed. Try `sudo ls -l /proc/N/exe` (where N is the PID of the CPU greedy process): it should identify the full pathname of the actual executable file that is being run. If you cannot get this information, or the file seems to have been deleted, that would strongly suggest it's probably malicious.

Comment: In the absence of any other information, I would suspect a cryptocurrency mining attack.This could be from a background process which starts and disowns child and child-child processes, so they get reparented to init such that it keeps as many active children as you have CPUs. They are probably not `-bash` logins -- that can be faked easily. Google `crypto mining malware` and see if it describes your issue.

Comment: You could try and `kill -STOP` these processes. If the process running them back isn't smart enough it won't spawn a new one then, giving you some relief to find the culprit (which by default I also assume to be some malware unless given more logs).

Comment: @telcoM i've tried your solution and gave this result
`root@vm2473309462:~# ls -l /proc/9559/exe --------->
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 11 05:39 /proc/9559/exe -> '/usr/bin/-bash (deleted)'`

Comment: That's definitely not a real `bash`, then. The use of minus sign in the filename makes the resulting process name look like a bash login session, and the fact the file has been deleted indicates it's trying to hide itself from inspection. See [How to deal with a compromised server](https://serverfault.com/q/218005/442837) originally on Server Fault.SE, and [also approved by Information Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39231).

Comment: Trash it, burn it, reinstall, restore from known good backup!